# SLURM: flag to auto-requeue jobs cancelled due to preemption?

Tags: hpc, slurm

I'm running the following job array on SLURM:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --array=1-1000
#SBATCH --partition=scavenge
#SBATCH --mem=2g
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00

module load Python/3.6.4-iomkl-2018a
python run.py ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}
```

Many of my jobs error out with:

```
slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 63830645 ON p08r06n17 CANCELLED AT 2020-08-18T21:40:52 DUE TO PREEMPTION ***
```

I'd like to requeue those jobs automatically if they're preempted. Is it possible to do so? Any pointers on this query would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This depends on how your cluster is set up. Preemption is handled by the [PreemptMode](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_PreemptMode) Option. If that is set to 'requeue', jobs are requeued, if either srun/sbatch parameter `requeue` was given, or [JobRequeue](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_JobRequeue) is set to 1 (see output of `scontrol show config`).

You can add the `requeue` parameter to your job script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --requeue
#SBATCH --array=1-1000
...
```

Or you can pass the requeue flag when submitting your job:

```
sbatch --requeue run.job
```

If that is not the case on your cluster, then you still might be able to work around this: The default [KillWait](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_KillWait) time is 30 seconds. Once your job is getting terminated (for any reason), There is a 30 second delay between the SIGTERM and SIGKILL signals. So you can `trap` the sigterm signal and requeue your job manually, e.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --array=1-1000
#SBATCH --partition=scavenge
#SBATCH --mem=2g
#SBATCH --time=1:00:00

trap 'scontrol requeue ${SLURM_JOB_ID}; exit 15' 15 
module load Python/3.6.4-iomkl-2018a
python run.py ${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID} &
wait
```

This requeues the job as soon as a SIGTERM arrives. Downside: If you want to properly cancel this job, you'll need to use `scancel -9 <jobid>`, as the default signal sent by scancel is SIGTERM.

Comment: Wow `scontrol show config` shows so much information! Thanks very much for this. I'm going to keep looking to see if there's a flag / parameter I can use to requeue, but this is super helpful!